# Cache invalidation strategy

Tags: caching, redis

In my current application, we are dealing with some information which **rarely changes**.
For performance optimization, we want to **store them in the cache**.
But the problem is in **invaliding these objects whenever these are updated**.
We have not finalized the caching product.
As we are building this application on Azure, we will probably use `Azure Redis cache`.
One strategy could be to add code in `Update API` which will invalidate object in the cache.
I am not sure if this is a clean way?
We do not want to go with **Cache Expiration** based on time (TTL).
Could you please suggest some other strategies used for cache invalidation?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Invalidate the cache during the *Update* stage is a viable approach, and was extremely used in the past.

You have two options here when the UPDATE happens:

1. You may try to **set the new value during update operation**, or
2. Just **delete the old one** and **update during a read operation**.

If you want an **[LRU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies#Least_recently_used_(LRU))**, then UPDATE may just delete the old value, and the first time the object will be fetched, you'll create it again after the read from the actual database. However, if you know that your cache is very small and you are using another main database for concerns different than data size, you may update directly during UPDATE.

However, all this is not enough to be completely consistent.
When you write to your DB, the `Redis` cache may be unavailable for a few seconds for example, so data remains not synchronized between the two.
What do you do in that case?
There are several options you could use at the same time.

1. Set a TTL anyway, so that eventually broken data is refreshed.
2. Use lazy read repair. When you read from the DB, from time to time check with the primary if the value matches. If not update the cached item (or delete it).
3. Use epochs or similar ways to access your data. Not always possible, however sometimes you access cached data about a given object. When possible you may change the object ID/handle every time you modify it, so that it is impossible that you access stale data in the cache: every key name refers to a *specific* version of your object.

So the del-cache-on-update and write-cache-on-read is the basic strategy, but you can employ other additional systems to eventually repair the inconsistencies.

There is another option actually instead of using the above options, which is to have a background process using Redis `SCAN` to verify key by key if there are inconsistencies. This process can be slow and can run against a replica of your database.

As you can see here the main idea is always the same: if an update to the cache fails, don't make it a permanent issue that will remain there potentially forever, give it a chance to fix itself at a later time.

Comment: `del-cache-on-update` might cause a stampede when fetch operation is called simultaneously and the value is not in the cache, all the requests will go to the database. It might be avoided using locking or other strategies. So updating your cache during read might be a better option.

Comment: how will del-cache-on-update prevent inconsistent data due to concurrent read-write? If a request reads an old value from DB and then another request updates new value to the DB, invalidate cache  but then the read request updates the cache with old data, we have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the lambda(ish) architecture works for your use case.

1. Real time updates for immediate business use
2. Batch data load to repair any failed records
3. Batch data load to delete any in invalid/archived records.

For real-time updates, you will have to work on the codebase of the application to write the data to both DB and cache.

For batch data load, you can look at data ingestion tools such as logstash/fluentd to "pull" the latest data from your database and push them over to the cache. This can be done based on a column that always increments (ID number or timestamp).

I have Oracle database at my end. The Logstash JDBC plugin does a decent job in pulling the latest records. The logstash output can be formatted and printed to a file that Redis can consume. I wrote a small bash script to orchestrate this. Tested for 3 million records and works alright.